# Socket.io expo react native clients repeatedly changing socket.id and shows disconnect=true

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo

I am new to socket.io and was using guide https://snack.expo.io/@alexandrius/socket.io-client

On my server side (node.js) i see that socket.id keeps changing repeatedly

[image]

And on by expo client side in console.log i see :
[image]

Here is my code for client side:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(socket);
    //socketIO();
    this.socket = io(URL, { transports: ["websocket"] });
    this.socket.on("connect", () => {
      this.setState({ isConnected: true });
    });

    this.socket.on("ping", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    GetLocation();
  }
```

When i connect to web page from phone it fires up socket and on server side does not change id repeatedly.

No sure is there any bug with expo react native socke.io  library or i am doing something wrong

Comment: had the same issue, changed to version 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it my upgrading my expo to the version 36